Discrete Hidden Markov Model with continuous observation
Say I have a HMM system that can be in any of $n$ discrete possible states - say they are numbered $1$ to $n$ and can even actually be these integers.
I know the transition matrix between different time steps (time is discrete as well).
Say my observations $Y$ are naturally continuous, eg : they are equal to the actual state value ($1$ to $n$), plus a gaussian noise of mean $0$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ with $\sigma$ not being insignificant - say $\sigma=1$.
From what I'm reading, a possibility would be to "discretize" or "bin" each observation, for example by turning into an $n$-dimensional discrete vector $Z$ with say $Z(i)=round(|Y-i|/\sigma)$.
But this is obviously suboptimal and quite unsatisfying, since in this example, I know / can provide probabilities or even the conditional pdf of $Y$ for every possible state.
In that case, can I use my knowledge of these probabilities / pdf directly and in a satisfying / simple manner with respect to the forward-backward algorithm and/or the Viterbi algorithm ?

Hidden Markov models with continuous observation variables are very common in some fields (e.g., finance, ecology). All the common algorithms can directly be extended to the continuous case by replacing probability mass functions by probability density functions, so there is no need to discretise the observations.
For example, you describe the following model:
$$
Y_t \mid \{ S_t = j \} \sim N(\mu_j, 1)
$$
where $S_t \in \{ 1, 2, \dots, K \}$ is the state variable, and $Y_t \in \mathbb{R}$ is the observation variable. The forward-backward and Viterbi algorithms are both written in terms of the state-dependent probability density (or mass) function. In the example, this is the density function of the normal distribution with state-dependent mean $\mu_j$ and variance 1:
$$
\begin{aligned}
b_j(y) & = f_{Y_t \vert S_t}(y \mid S_t = j) \\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left( -\frac{(y - \mu_j)^2}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
To make this more concrete, say we have realisations $Y_1 = y_1, Y_2 = y_2, \dots$, and we are interested in calculating the forward variables $\alpha_t(j)$ (at time $t$ in state $j$). We would plug the p.d.f. above into the usual steps of the forward algorithm (e.g., Equations 19-20 of Rabiner 1989):

Initialisation

$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha_1(j) & = \Pr(S_1 = j) b_j (y_1) \\
& = \Pr(S_1 = j) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left( -\frac{(y_1 - \mu_j)^2}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Induction

$$
\begin{aligned}
\alpha_{t+1}(j) & = \left[ \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_t(i) P_{ij} \right] b_j(y_{t+1}) \\
& = \left[ \sum_{i=1}^K \alpha_t(i) P_{ij} \right] \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left( -\frac{(y_{t+1} - \mu_j)^2}{2} \right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Similar calculations would be used for the backward algorithm, Viterbi algorithm, etc.
